# ADB Connection Disappears in Android Studio after enabling adb integration

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, visual-studio-emulator

I use Visual Studio Emulator to debug my projects.
But now my Emulator is not shown when the adb integration is enabled and 
when i disabled it is shown again.
What is Happening there and how can i debug again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only allows one Debugging console, Such as Android Device Monitor or in your case Visual Studio Emulator. Under tools->Android->Adb Integration is how you renable it

Comment: Yea, thats all i have befor. But when i renable it the Device disappears and thats the Problem. The Device disappears when i enable the adb integration.

Comment: it only allows one connection Either or Not both.

Comment: Thanks, i had to kill  the default adb server and relaunch the vs adb server.